# How to optimize two for loops (a for loop inside a for loop) in java

Tags: java

I have following problem:

- I have a very long string `String str = "abcdefghiart----"`
- Now I want to iterate over string and want to find the first duplicate character in string
- This I can achieve with applying two for loops to search first duplicate
- This approach works fine but iteration complexity will be very high in case string very large and only last two characters are duplicate

  Now I want to minimize the complexity and optimize this code. I can use `foreach` loop too to iterate but still it will be two `foreach` loop. I don't want to use any system library. Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method to find the first duplicate character in a string.

```
 public static String findFirstDuplicate(String string){

                 for(int i=0;i<string.length()-1; i++){
                     String c=string.charAt(i)+"";
                     if(string.indexOf(c, i+1)>-1)
                         return  c;
                 }

                 return null;
  }
```

AS for optimization, you can optimise it by customizing Merge Sort to find duplicate value and terminate when a duplicate is found. It is a bit complicated to explain here but you'll be able to find the first duplicate in O(nlogn) at worst case using modified merge sort algorithm.

Comment: String c=string.charAt(i)+"" is extremely inefficient (unnecessary string concatenation), especially since string.indexOf() can take a char.

Answer (score 3):

```
BitSet seenCharacters = new BitSet();
for(int i=0;i<str.length(); i++) {
  if(seenCharacters.get(str.charAt(i))) {
    return str.charAt(i); // duplicate
  }
  seenCharacters.set(i);
}
```

...Straightforward enough, no?

Comment: Or in English: there's no such optimization; find a better algorithm than the one at hand.

Comment: Thanks for response Louis. But here I don't want to use any system class.

Comment: ...I have _no idea_ what you mean by "no system class" if `HashMap` is okay and `BitSet` isn't.  `BitSet` is in `java.util`, just like `HashMap`.

Comment: Sorry Louis.
Using this as BitSet is little complex than using HashSet(Not HashMap).

Answer (score 2):

I would approach the problem with a different solution. I would use a hashmap (or any of it derivatives), the key would be a character and the value would be null.

Then I would traverse the string, getting one character at a time, for each character I got I will try to insert an entry to the hashmap. If I failed to insert it then I know the character (which is the key itself) is a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Gilbeg. I think this only I will have to do. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Also it would be optimized more if I use 'Set' or 'HashSet' because it does not allow duplicate values and if you try to insert the same value again, it will return false. And no need to use key,value Map

Answer (score 0):

Define an int array of size [26] , one slot for each alphabet

Iterate through the string and for each alphabet check if the slot's value is > 0 if it is then the alphabet which corresponds to the slot is the duplicate character , if it is 0 , just increment it and keep moving forward

Comment: This is incorrect. You are not keeping into consideration that Java uses 16-bit encoding for Strings, because of differenct character sets. Your solution may work for Latin-based languages, but hardly for any other.